# POST request with express

Tags: node.js, express

i have a router file that works for

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log("Get Request accepted retun login page");

router.post('/', function(req, res){

}

router.get('/register.html', function(res, req){

}
```

I'm trying to submit data from register.html with a button but it routes to the .post('/')

instead of .post('/register.html')

is there a way to tell which page the post request was sent from?

in my app.js file I have

```
const userRoute = require('./routes/userlogin')
app.use('/', userRoute)
```

Comment: can you post more code? As it's vague what you are trying to accomplish here. And here you;ve only one post request, so it will definitely call this  ('/")  route here. If you want to post from your path register then write like this `router.post('/register')`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In my register.html file I had action='/' instead of action='/register.html'.

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.